# Trying to convert Byte[] to bitmap but giving error saying "parameter is not valid" in c#

Tags: c#, bitmap

```
public class PrintPage
{        
    public void buildPdf(string url)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = PrintHelpPage(url);
        Document dc = new Document();
        PdfWriter pdfWrt = PdfWriter.GetInstance(dc, new FileStream(@"D:/Experiment/Sample.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        dc.Open();
        iTextSharp.text.Image pdfImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(bmp, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        dc.Add(pdfImage);
        dc.Close();
    }
    private Bitmap PrintHelpPage(string url)
    {
        if (url.ToUpper()=="DEFAULT")
        {
            url = @"https://www.google.com";
        }
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Enc); 
        string sDoc = sr.ReadToEnd();               
        sr.Close();            
        byte[] by = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sDoc);
        Bitmap bm = ByteToImage(by);            
        return bm;            
    }
    public static Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
    {
        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mStream.Write(blob, 0, blob.Length);
            mStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream);
            return bm;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: Subsequent to your comment:

> actually I am trying to capture whole page as a picture of a random website to convert as PDF

Then you're going about it the wrong way. You'll need to start a browser (e.g. a [`System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and somehow do a screen capture. This will be non-trivial. It's also important that you understand *why* your current approach doesn't work - it suggests a fundamental misunderstanding of how the web works.

**Original answer**

This is your most fundamental problem:

```
System.Text.Encoding Enc = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Enc); 
string sDoc = sr.ReadToEnd();               
sr.Close();            
byte[] by = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sDoc);
```

You're reading an *image* as if it were a text file. It won't be. You'll be losing data like this.

Additionally, you're closing the memory stream that you're passing into the `Bitmap` constructor - you shouldn't do that.

You should just copy the response stream directly into a `MemoryStream`, and use that for the `Bitmap`:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
using (var input = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    input.CopyTo(stream);
}
stream.Position = 0;
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
```

Oh, and you should also use a `using` statement for the response, otherwise that won't get disposed, which can cause timeouts for future requests due to connection pooling.

Comment: @Herohanif: Well is the URL *actually* the URL for an image? (The Google URL certainly isn't an image, for example...)

Comment: No it is not Image url, actually I am trying to capture whole page as a picture of a random website to convert as PDF.

Comment: @Herohanif: Well you're not going to have any luck by doing that this way - you need to start a browser basically, and take a screenshot. And in future, please give more explanation in your question - you didn't mention that *at all*. Questions should pretty much always have explanatory text, not just code. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Thanks. so I will do it as you say. Is there any decoding problem is arising doing this way? I mainly find "((System.IO.Stream)(stream)).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException" error .

Comment: @Herohanif: Well yes, you're trying to decode HTML as if it's a bitmap. It's not clear where `ReadTimeout` comes into it though, as that occurs nowhere in your question...